# Autocepstrum accelerate framework

Tags: objective-c, fft, accelerate-framework

How can i do autocepstrum (cepstrum + autocorrelation) analysis with accelerate framework? Is there any example code or project?

Answer (score 1):

An auto cepstrum is the cepstrum of the auto correlation.

I explain how to do an auto correlation here:

[Auto-correlating the cepstrum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305359/auto-correlating-the-cepstrum/22420998#22420998)

To calculate the cepstrum you would do the following:

1. Perform FFT of the top half of the autocorrelation.
2. Take the abs of each of the complex elements (r^2 + i^2).
3. Take the log of each element.
4. Perform inverse FFT.

Now interestingly one of the ways to perform an auto correlation is via an FFT as follows:

1. Pad the data to twice its length with 0s.
2. Perform FFT.
3. Multiply each element with the conjugate of itself.
4. Perform Inverse FFT.

This introduces an interesting optimisation the final IFFT of the auto correlation calculation and the first FFT of the cepstrum can be eliminated.

ie

1. Pad the data to twice its length with 0s.
2. Perform FFT.
3. Multiply each element with the conjugate of itself.
4. Take the abs of each of the complex elements (r^2 + i^2).
5. Take the log of each element.
6. Perform inverse FFT.